# Inserting php array data into mysql isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello I have an array $name[] that I am trying to insert into the second field of my table but it's not working (table remains completely blank). I cannot find the error in my code what am I doing wrong?

```
$username="us";
$password="pw";
$database="db";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "error");

$i=0;
while ($i < 5) {


$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','$name[i]','','')";
mysql_query($query);

$i++
}

mysql_close();
```

Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: Protip: using a for-loop will save you 2 lines of code.  for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { ... }

Comment: This solved it.

There is an error in the above in the while loop, I don't know what it is. But replacing the while loop with the for loop solves it.

Comment: The error I think btw was $i++ was missing a ; after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a constant `i` instead of `$i` for the key of `$name`. So try this:

```
"INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','".$name[$i]."','','')"
```

You should also escape the value for the MySQL query using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
"INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($name[$i])."','','')"
```

Comment: Or this: "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','{$name[$i]}','','')"

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, all that will do is put an entry with columns 1, 3, and 4 blank, and column 2 with the value `$name[i]`. To have a variable in a string, it needs to be in double quotes. But I don't see the point of doing that when you can just have the variable.

Also, `$name[i]` is supposed to be `$name[$i]`.

Comment: I changed it to $name[$i] and it made no difference. I am leaving the other columns blank for now as I try and just get one column of data in and when it works I can get my other arrays into the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to escape when you are concatenating queries like that.

$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name[$i]) . "', '', '')";

If you don't you might be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) badness

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query like this:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will give you a better idea of what you're doing wrong if there's a problem with your query. You may also want to print your SQL for debugging:

```
echo "Query $i: $query<br />"
```